# Glassfish authentication : can the realm be an external database

Tags: authentication, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I am completely new to login and authentication concepts. I am working on a Glassfish web application that should present general content to any visitor, and some extra content for registered users logged in with username and password.

I have been reading the Java EE tutorial about security, and I thought that the Form-based or HTTP authentication would fulfill my needs ( the visitor is asked for credentials when trying to browse a secured content ).

However, my first guess was that the registred users should be stored in an external database along with their hashed and salted password.
The security for web application in Glassfish seems to rely on the realm populated manually directly on the application server ( defining user and groups and mapping them to the Roles in the application ).

Did I misunderstood what security on Glassfish is intented to ? Or can a realm be a external database outside the application server ? Any link to documentation on this topic would be useful to me.

Thank you in advance

Tart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible.
In Glassfish, go to Configuration/Security/Realms, create a new realm and set the classname to com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.
Indicate the JDBC Resource bound to the database, and indicate the table and the columns where username/password are stored. The database shall also contains a table for the groups which the user must belong to be granted access. Indicate those also.

In the application, set up the web.xml and sun-web.xml with the realm name as usual.

Comment: Docs: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4495/ggmww?a=view

Blog entry that leverages MySQL: http://blogs.sun.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish_with_mysql

Comment: Although it is almost possible, I don't think you can have the JDBCRealm salt the password before hashing, which is actually a serious vulnerability imho. Also, the realm implementation of Glassfish has serious shortcomings when it comes to group/role mapping, because roles have to be 'hard-coded' in sun-web.xml. There is a way around this using views, but it is a contrived solution. You can solve the salt problem by implementing your own realm, but solving the group/role mapping issue is harder I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about jdbc realm in glassfish with scenario you described: http://java-cookbook.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html